# Syntax error: "}" unexpected (expecting "fi")

Tags: bash

Here's a simple shell script downloaded from Atlassian and slightly adjusted to meet all suggestions found so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

# RUN_AS: The user to run fisheye as. Its recommended that you create a separate user account for security reasons
RUN_AS=fisheye

# FISHEYE_HOME: The path to the FishEye installation. Its recommended to create a symbolic link to the latest version so
# the process will still work after upgrades.
FISHEYE_HOME="/opt/atlassian/fisheye"

fisheyectl() {
        ARGS="--Xdisable-tags --Xenable-git-content-hash-resolving-heuristic"
        CMD="$FISHEYE_HOME/bin/fisheyectl.sh $1"
        if [ $1 == "run" ]
        then
            CMD="nohup $CMD $ARGS >> $FISHEYE_HOME/var/log/nohup.out &";
        fi
        if [ "$USER" != "$RUN_AS" ]
        then
                su - "$RUN_AS" -c "$CMD";
        else
                sh -c "$CMD";
        fi
}

case "$1" in
        start)
                fisheyectl run
                ;;
        stop)
                fisheyectl stop
                ;;
        restart)
                fisheyectl stop
                sleep 10
                fisheyectl run
                ;;
        *)
                echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
esac

exit 0
```

I have run this through dos2unix locally. On executing:

```
fisheye: 23: fisheye: Syntax error: "}" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure you copied and pasted it precisely as it's being executed?

Comment: The error in full: jamesg@agile:/etc/init.d$ sudo ./fisheye start
./fisheye: 23: ./fisheye: Syntax error: "}" unexpected (expecting "fi")

Comment: The error implies mismatched `if` and `fi` lines, but they're perfectly matched in the code you posted. Check for invisible characters.

Comment: In particular, make sure the file doesn't have CRLF line endings.

Comment: The semicolons in `fisheyctl` are unnecessary; could they be confusing `dos2unix`?

Comment: I'd actually say the opposite. Use the semicolons so that the line-ending interpretation doesn't mess with flow control.

Comment: Carriage returns would still be a problem; following a semicolon they would be interpreted as a command name, since `bash` doesn't recognize them as whitespace. However, the OP mentioned using `dos2unix`, so I thought perhaps something was causing it to work improperly.

Comment: I've tried with and without the semicolons at the end of statements. I have also run bash -n fisheye.sh (the name of the script) and the syntax error still appears. I looked within vi using :set list, found a tab insert and replaced with spaces to be consistent but still no join at bash -n.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/mBQkv0K4 Is the current incarnation, hardly changed. The error now reads fisheye: line 23: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
fisheye: line 23: `}'

Comment: I replaced the file with that copied back from this web page and the syntax check passes. I can only assume that :set list failed to show some dodgy character...

Comment: Per michael's answer, the `if [ $1 == "run" ]` may still fail at some point. To avoid this in a non-bash specific way, change that to `if [ "x$1" == "xrun" ]`

Comment: @kfsone: `if [ "$1" = "run" ]` should be sufficient; only very old implementations need the leading `x` to avoid an empty string. (A quoted empty string is a valid token.)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and it turned out I had to change the #/bin/sh line into #/bin/bash

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if [ $1 == "run" ]
```

to

```
if [ ${1:-X} = "run" ]
```

Comment: The shebang is "#!/bin/sh" not "#!/bin/bash" so that might not work.

Comment: FYI Normally /bin/sh is a symlink - in older versions of Linux distros often to /bin/bash.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if [ $1 == "run" ]
```

to this:

```
if [ "$1" = "run" ]
```

In bash's built-in `[` command, `==` is a synonym for `=`, but not all implementations of the `[` (`test`) command recognize `==`. `=` is the original operator for string equality comparison -- and your script has `#!/bin/sh`, which may or may not be bash-compatible.

I've also added double quotes around `$1`. They're not strictly necessary in this case, since you always call `fisheyectl()` with a single word argument, but it's a good idea in general to enclose variable references in single quotes. (Without the quotes, if you called `fisheyectl()` with no arguments, you'd have `if [ = "run" ]`, which is a syntax error.)